# Why does scikit-learn's GridSearchCV take only first parameter as best estimator?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, svc

I am trying to find out best estimator in SVC Model using GridSearchCV, Here is My code and Output

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
param_grid = {'C': [5e3,1e3, 1e4, 5e4, 1e5], 'gamma': [0.0005, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.1]}
clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight='balanced', probability=True), param_grid)
clf = clf.fit(emb_array, label)
print("Best estimator found by grid search:")
print(clf.best_estimator_)
```

**Output**

```
Best estimator found by grid search:
SVC(C=5000.0, cache_size=200, class_weight='balanced', coef0=0.0,
    decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=0.0005, kernel='rbf',
    max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001,
    verbose=False)
```

**If I change `param_grid` to**

```
   param_grid = {'C': [1e3, 5e3, 1e4, 5e4, 1e5], 'gamma': [0.0001, 0.0005, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.1]}
```

**Then Output**

```
Best estimator found by grid search:
SVC(C=1000.0, cache_size=200, class_weight='balanced', coef0=0.0,
    decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=0.0001, kernel='rbf',
    max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001,
    verbose=False)
```

If it is taking only first arguments as `best_estimator_` best then what is the use of `GridSearchCV`?

Answer (score 1):

`best_estimator_` is returning the estimator with the highest score / smallest loss, not the estimator with the first argument. What you are seeing is likely an artifact of your data and the nature of your hyperparamater sweep. As an example, here is the same code on the Iris data.

```py
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
​
iris = datasets.load_iris()
​
param_grid = {'C': [5e3,1e3, 1e4, 5e4, 1e5], 'gamma': [1.0, 0.0005, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.1]}
clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight='balanced', probability=True), param_grid)
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
print("Best estimator found by grid search:")
print(clf.best_estimator_)
Best estimator found by grid search:
SVC(C=1000.0, break_ties=False, cache_size=200, class_weight='balanced',
    coef0=0.0, decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=0.0005,
    kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None,
    shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

The first arguments are not the ones that end up being the best ones.

As a note, you also may want to restructure your code a bit. `fit` also modifies the estimator object in-place, and it's best practice to explicitly define an estimator outside of the `GridSearchCV` object, like this:

```py
...
svc = SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight='balanced', probability=True)
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, param_grid)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
...
```

Comment: could you please explain what is going on in my case? why does it take only first arguments of c and gamma